# Show Date-Values on X-Axis in locale depending format ngx-charts / d3

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, localization, datetime-format

I have a Webapp using Angular v4.0.1 and ngx-charts (uses d3) v5.1.2 creating a line-chart where the x-axis has date-values.

My Problem is that the x-axis does not show the german time-format. So I found out how I can set locale formatting for d3:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

import * as formatDE from "d3-format/locale/de-DE.json";
import * as timeFormatDE from "d3-time-format/locale/de-DE.json";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    var formatBefore = d3.timeFormat("%A");
    console.log('Before: '+formatBefore(new Date));
    // output: Thursday -> OK

    d3.formatDefaultLocale(formatDE);
    d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(timeFormatDE);

    var formatAfter = d3.timeFormat("%A");
    console.log('After: '+formatAfter(new Date));
    // output: Donnerstag -> YES, nice
  }
}
```

But this has now effect for the x-axis! The date and time-value are still in english format.

[image]

Comment: Hello, in the end you could change the language I have the same problem. If so, how did you do it? a greeting

Answer (score 13):

Although ngx-charts wraps d3 not all d3 tricks work with it. Most ngx-charts components have an `xAxisTickFormatting` input that you connect to your own formatting function, e.g.:

```html
<!-- some-component.html -->
<ngx-charts-line-chart ... [xAxisTickFormatting]="dateTickFormatting" ...>
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

```ts
// some-component.ts
function dateTickFormatting(val: any): string {
  if (val instanceof Date) {
    return (<Date>val).toLocaleString('de-DE');
  }
}
```

[**Updated 2018-11-03 with a more detailed example**]

Pay attention to the [Date.toLocaleString() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

- the first parameter is a locale string representing the culture you wish to format for (e.g.: 'en-US', 'de-DE', 'fr-FR')
- the second parameter is an options object that allows you to change the format of different date/time parts.

Starting a new Angular project from scratch to demo this fully...

```
$ npm -g install generator-ngx-rocket@1.3.3

$ mkdir charts-demo; cd charts-demo; ngx new charts-demo
> Web app
> Progressive: Yes
> Bootstrap
> Authentication: No
> Lazy loading: No
> Analytics: No
> Prettier: Yes

$ npm i @swimlane/ngx-charts@10.0.0
```

In app.module.ts:

```ts
import {NgxChartsModule} from '@swimlane/ngx-charts'; //<<-- Add this
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule,
    NgxChartsModule, //<<-- Add this
    CoreModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In app.component.html:

```html
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
<!-- Add this... -->
<ngx-charts-line-chart
    [legend]="true"
    [results]="chartData"
    [view]="[1100,320]"
    [xAxis]="true"
    [xAxisTickFormatting]="this.dateTickFormatting">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Finally, in app.component.ts:

```ts
// ...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // Add this...
  // Note the Date objects for the names (X Axis values)...
  chartData: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'Series 1',
      series: [
        { name: new Date("2017-12-01"), value: 0 },
        { name: new Date("2018-01-01"), value: 1 },
        { name: new Date("2018-02-01"), value: 1 },
        { name: new Date("2018-03-01"), value: 2 },
        { name: new Date("2018-04-01"), value: 3 },
        { name: new Date("2018-05-01"), value: 5 },
        { name: new Date("2018-06-01"), value: 8 },
        { name: new Date("2018-07-01"), value: 13 },
        { name: new Date("2018-08-01"), value: 21 },
        { name: new Date("2018-09-01"), value: 34 },
        { name: new Date("2018-10-01"), value: 55 },
        { name: new Date("2018-11-01"), value: 89 },
        { name: new Date("2018-12-01"), value: 144 }
      ]
    }
  ];
  constructor(
  // ...
  // in ngOnInit()...
      .subscribe(event => {
        const title = event['title'];
        if (title) {

this.titleService.setTitle(this.translateService.instant(title));
        }
        //Add this: Record the new language...
        environment.defaultLanguage = this.translateService.currentLang;
        //Add this: Refresh the ngx-chart...
        this.chartData = [... this.chartData];
      });
  // ...
  // new method, dateTickFormatting...
  dateTickFormatting(val: any): String {
    if (val instanceof Date) {
      var options = { month: 'long' };
      //return (<Date>val).toLocaleString('de-DE', options);
      return (<Date>val).toLocaleString(environment.defaultLanguage, options);
    }
  }
}
```

What we've done so far enables you to switch between the out-of-the-box languages for an ngx-rocket application, en-US and fr-FR:

[image: en-US].

[image: fr-FR].

You can add some basic plumbing and translations to enable switching to de-DE as well:

[image: de-DE].

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, in the end you could change the language I have the same problem. If so, how did you do it? a greeting – Manolait 17 mins ago   edit

Comment: @Manolait My answer shows how I did it. Make sure that your X axis values are actually Date objects (i.e.: `new Date('2017-12-31')` ) and not strings made to look like Dates (i.e.: `'2017-12-31'`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using ngx-chart version 18.0.1 and charts have two attribute [xAxisTicks] and [yAxisTicks], they give data in any[] type and if you pass them data and that data matches with your chart data it will just show yAxisTicks Data.for Example in my project i needed to show xAxis just per days and didnt want to show them per hour and minute:

```
xAxisTicks: string[] = [];

 private addXAxis(xAxisValue: string) {
    if (this.xAxisTicks.find(xAxis => xAxis.slice(0, 10) === xAxisValue.slice(0, 10)) == undefined) {
      this.xAxisTicks.push(xAxisValue);
    }
  }
```

as you can see i just add some of the times into my array and because i use persian date i had to do this in that way

and here its the html

```
      <ngx-charts-line-chart
        [yAxis]="yAxis"
        [xAxis]="true"
        [xAxisTicks]="xAxisTicks"
        [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
        [results]="lineChartData"
      >
      </ngx-charts-line-chart>
```